# How to get the removed reaction response?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for(
    'reaction_add',
    check = lambda reaction, user: reaction.message == message and str(reaction.emoji) in ['1️⃣', '2️⃣', '3️⃣', '4️⃣', '◀️', '▶️', '❌'],
    timeout = 60
)
```

It return a `reaction.emoji` value when people react on the message.

But when people remove the reaction of the message, it won't works.

How do I get the removed reaction value?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `on_reaction_remove(reaction, user)` or `on_raw_reaction_remove(payload)` (if message is not in cache [old]) to monitor removed reactions from messages.

**Documentation below:**

[discord.on_reaction_remove](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=reaction#discord.on_reaction_remove)

`Called when a message has a reaction removed from it. Similar to on_message_edit, if the message is not found in the internal message cache, then this event will not be called.`

[discord.on_raw_reaction_remove](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=reaction#discord.on_raw_reaction_remove)

`Called when a message has a reaction removed. Unlike on_reaction_remove(), this is called regardless of the state of the internal message cache.`